# Odoo server error happened to me while adding a new user. How do I resolve it?

Tags: python, python-3.x, odoo, odoo-15

I was trying to add a new user to my Odoo-15 community edition when suddenly this error code appeared to me:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_mail_server.py", line 617, in send_email
    smtp.send_message(message, smtp_from, smtp_to_list)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/smtplib.py", line 986, in send_message
    return self.sendmail(from_addr, to_addrs, flatmsg, mail_options,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/smtplib.py", line 908, in sendmail
    raise SMTPDataError(code, resp)
smtplib.SMTPDataError: (553, b'Relaying disallowed as info@zt.sa')

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/addons/mail/models/mail_mail.py", line 356, in send
    self.browse(batch_ids)._send(
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/addons/mail/models/mail_mail.py", line 464, in _send
    res = IrMailServer.send_email(
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_mail_server.py", line 628, in send_email
    raise MailDeliveryException(_("Mail Delivery Failed"), msg)
odoo.addons.base.models.ir_mail_server.MailDeliveryException: ('Mail Delivery Failed', "Mail delivery failed via SMTP server 'None'.\nSMTPDataError: 553\nRelaying disallowed as info@zt.sa")

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_http.py", line 237, in _dispatch
    result = request.dispatch()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/http.py", line 687, in dispatch
    result = self._call_function(**self.params)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/http.py", line 359, in _call_function
    return checked_call(self.db, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/service/model.py", line 94, in wrapper
    return f(dbname, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/http.py", line 348, in checked_call
    result = self.endpoint(*a, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/http.py", line 910, in __call__
    return self.method(*args, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/http.py", line 535, in response_wrap
    response = f(*args, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 1326, in call_kw
    return self._call_kw(model, method, args, kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 1318, in _call_kw
    return call_kw(request.env[model], method, args, kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/api.py", line 462, in call_kw
    result = _call_kw_model_create(method, model, args, kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/api.py", line 442, in _call_kw_model_create
    result = method(recs, *args, **kwargs)
  File "<decorator-gen-310>", line 2, in create
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/api.py", line 412, in _model_create_multi
    return create(self, [arg])
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/addons/website_slides/models/res_users.py", line 13, in create
    users = super(Users, self).create(vals_list)
  File "<decorator-gen-211>", line 2, in create
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/api.py", line 413, in _model_create_multi
    return create(self, arg)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/addons/digest/models/res_users.py", line 12, in create
    users = super(ResUsers, self).create(vals_list)
  File "<decorator-gen-166>", line 2, in create
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/api.py", line 413, in _model_create_multi
    return create(self, arg)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/addons/note/models/res_users.py", line 17, in create
    users = super().create(vals_list)
  File "<decorator-gen-159>", line 2, in create
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/api.py", line 413, in _model_create_multi
    return create(self, arg)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/addons/gamification/models/res_users.py", line 44, in create
    res = super(Users, self).create(values_list)
  File "<decorator-gen-150>", line 2, in create
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/api.py", line 413, in _model_create_multi
    return create(self, arg)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/addons/auth_signup/models/res_users.py", line 243, in create
    users_with_email.with_context(create_user=True).action_reset_password()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/addons/auth_signup/models/res_users.py", line 202, in action_reset_password
    template.send_mail(user.id, force_send=force_send, raise_exception=True, email_values=email_values)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/addons/mail/models/mail_template.py", line 332, in send_mail
    mail.send(raise_exception=raise_exception)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/addons/mail/models/mail_mail.py", line 365, in send
    smtp_session.quit()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/smtplib.py", line 1004, in quit
    res = self.docmd("quit")
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/smtplib.py", line 431, in docmd
    self.putcmd(cmd, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/smtplib.py", line 378, in putcmd
    self.send(f'{s}{CRLF}')
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/smtplib.py", line 365, in send
    raise SMTPServerDisconnected('please run connect() first')
Exception

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/http.py", line 643, in _handle_exception
    return super(JsonRequest, self)._handle_exception(exception)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/http.py", line 301, in _handle_exception
    raise exception.with_traceback(None) from new_cause
smtplib.SMTPServerDisconnected: please run connect() first
```

I did try to change the smtp server to gmail and zoho but it didn't work.

This error is new to me and I don't know how to handle it.

Comment: Are you sure your outgoing email server configuration is working? Alternatively or as workaround just deactivate it, create the user and activate it again.

Comment: And for your email configuration you probably should search for "553 relaying disallowed" to find out what to do.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I reconfigured the email server and it is working now.